# backtracking in capturing group

Tags: regex, pcre

In the first image, it does start backtracking to find `|`.

[image]

But in the second image, it does not start backtracking to find `|`.

No backtracking in the capturing group?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second regex you have an alternation that doesn't exist in first one. That alternation brings an opportunity for engine to be chosen as a path to success.

So as soon as first side of alternation fails, second side applies and coincidentally that literal dot character at the end of input string matches `\.` in second side of alternation immediately, hence no backtrack to a `|`.

Remove it and you will see similar backtracking steps again:

```
\S+(\|\d+\|\S+\.)
```

Comment: I understood it because of you.:) Thank you very much.